# How to unit test a gRPC server's asynchronous methods?

Tags: grpc-python

Following the suggestions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718078/how-to-write-a-grpc-python-unittest) I was able to unit test the synchronous methods of my gRPC service (which is built with the [`grpc.aio`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc_asyncio.html) API) using the [`grpc_testing`](https://pypi.org/project/grpcio-testing/) library. However, when I follow [this example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/7f6a27a4d3675adc0de263d291346aab2f46e733/src/python/grpcio_tests/tests/testing/_server_test.py#L77-L100) on an asynchronous method of my gRPC service I get:

```
ERROR    grpc_testing._server._rpc:_rpc.py:92 Exception calling application!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jp/venvs/grpc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc_testing/_server/_service.py", line 63, in _stream_response
    response = copy.deepcopy(next(response_iterator))
TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not an iterator
```

Looking through the [`grpc_testing`](https://pypi.org/project/grpcio-testing/) codebase and searching more broadly, I cannot find examples of unit testing async gRPC methods.  The closest thing I could find is an [unmerged branch](https://github.com/nils-werner/pytest-grpc/tree/asyncio) of [`pytest-grpc`](https://github.com/kataev/pytest-grpc), but [the example service](https://github.com/nils-werner/pytest-grpc/blob/asyncio/pytest_grpc/tests/servicer.py) does not have any async methods.

Can anyone share an example of unit testing an asynchronous gRPC method in python?

Comment: I have come up with an answer with the simplest settings
[How to do unit tests on python async functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68410035/how-to-do-unit-tests-on-python-async-functions?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gRPC Testing is a nice project. But we need engineering resources to make it support asyncio, and mostly importantly, adopt the existing APIs to asyncio's philosophy.

For testing gRPC asyncio, I would recommend just use `pytest` which has `pytest-asyncio` to smoothly test out asyncio features. Here is an example: [code](https://github.com/googleapis/python-api-core/blob/master/tests/asyncio/test_grpc_helpers_async.py).

Answer (score 4):

I followed @Lidi's recommendations (thank you) and implemented the tests using `pytest-asyncio`.  For what it's worth, here is a basic example testing an async stream stream method:

```py
import mock
import grpc
import pytest

from tokenize_pb2 import MyMessage
from my_implementation import MyService

async def my_message_generator(messages):
    for message in messages:
        yield message

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_my_async_stream_stream_method():
    service = MyService()
    my_messages = my_message_generator([MyMessage(), MyMessage()])
    mock_context = mock.create_autospec(spec=grpc.aio.ServicerContext)
    response = service.MyStreamStreamMethod(my_messages, mock_context)
    results = [x async for x in response]
    assert results == expected_results
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution given in [Joshua's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67100327/20397892) also works with python `unittest` framework utilizing the `unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase` class. For example:

```
import mock
import grpc
import unittest

from example_pb2 import MyRequestMessage
from my_implementation import MyService

class Tests(unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.service = MyService()
        self.mock_context = mock.create_autospec(spec=grpc.aio.ServicerContext)

    async def test_subscribe_unary_stream(self):
        response = self.service.MyUnaryStreamMethod(MyRequestMessage(), self.mock_context)
        async for result in response:
            self.assertIsNotNone(result)
```

While this allows testing of the actual business logic in the RPC functions, it falls short of `grpcio-testing` in terms of service features like response codes, timeouts etc.