# Python test grpc client

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, grpc

I've written a Python GRPC client and would like to be able to test it using Pytest. What I would like to do is mock out GRPC server response to be the same response every time. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Can you be specific on which libraries you rely on for network calls? Mocking depends on the implementation.

Comment: I'm using grpc library. My idea is to mock somehow grpc server response, so I can test client code.

Comment: Maybe this thread can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718078/how-to-write-a-grpc-python-unittest